# How to roll up percentages of children in hierarchy?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've been on this problem for a few days and can't seem to figure out a solution.

I have this data set of tasks with allocated levels (from level 0 to 5) on the hierarchy and '% Complete'. Some tasks have children and some who don't.

I want to calculate the average of the children tasks and allocate that as the percentage of the parent task. If the task is the end of the node (i.e. no children below it) I'd take the percentage complete as the value inside '% Complete'.

It needs to be a calculated column so that it is not responsive to any filters. The idea was to filter the tasks out based on their task level and their roll up value not be affected by this.

For each task, it lists all the parents up to the top level.

For example, Row 13 lists tasks Mondarra RBI at Level 2. There are three items under Mondarra RBI at Level 3, so the new calculated column value for % Complete for this task will be (0 + 1 + 1)/3 = 0.67.

[image: screenshot of data]

Here's my attempt:

```
 CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('FE Roadmap'[% Complete]), 
    FILTER('FE Roadmap',
    AND(PATHCONTAINS('FE Roadmap'[Path], 'FE Roadmap'[Task]), 'FE Roadmap'[IsParent] = "No")
)
```

)

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some sample data? 
Also, I guess (0+1+1)/3 should equal 0.67 not 0.33?

Comment: Hey @OscarLar, here's the file for testing.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4u6hwnpgn1e1r9/FE%20Roadmap.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Have you even tried finding a solution for it!!! It would be better to show some ground work you did as a reference.

Comment: @Mboolean, yep I put my attempt in my edit.

Comment: You need to re-design your table. In its current form, I don't this your goal is achievable. This might help: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/